# Offline playback for encrypted HLS content in iOS

Tags: ios, aes, offline, playback, http-live-streaming

I am trying to implement online and offline video playback using HLS.I am able to play online encrypted HLS content, but i am facing issues with offline encrypted content. Can anyone guide, how to implement offline encrypted hls content play back in iOS.